# How to change the color of the arrow in the dropdown box

Tags: google-app-maker

I am trying to change the color of the arrow in the dropdown boxes. Is that possible? I can change the background color, but not the arrow itself.

```
.app-Dropdown.ArrowColor .app-Dropdown-Arrow{
  ????: #29B6F6;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can customize particular instance of dropdown:

```
.app-YourPage-YourDropdown-Arrow:after {
  color: green;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

or you can create variant and apply it for all dropdowns you need:

```
.app-Dropdown--Custom .app-Dropdown-Arrow:after {
  color: green;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

[image: Custom widget variant]

**NOTE:** Please, keep in mind that you'll need additional styles for :active, :focus, and :disabled states...

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for and worked perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: You are welcome! Don't forget to accept the answer to help others ;)